# Understanding tensor transformation under coordinate rotation formula

Tags: tensors, transformation, rotations, classical-mechanics, change-of-basis

Given a Cartesian vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and suppose we wish to find the coordinates $(x'_1, x'_2, x'_3)$ of $x$ in a new rotated coordinate system  that shares the same origin with original coordinate system.

One can show that $x'_j = x_k C_{ki}$, where  $C_{ki}$ is the $3 \times 3$ matrix of direction cosines, and the proof is relatively easy.

Now, given a second order tensor $T_{ij}$, my textbook defines the transformation under the new rotated coordinate system as $$ T'_{mn} = C_{im}C_{jn}T_{ij}$$

Yet, the above formula is given with no proof, only a reference to Mechanics of Deformable Bodies (1964) book by Sommerfeld, which I don't have access to. I tried to prove it myself with no luck.

Note: I'm a beginner in tensor calculus, so please go easy on me.

Comment: Is it just the ordering $C_{im}C_{jn}T_{ij}=(C^\top)_{mi}T_{ij}C_{jn}=(C^\top TC)_{mn}$, do you understand the implied summation convention? Do you have a problem with the coordinates, which are contravariant functionals of the vector, being arranged in row vector format?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am okay with summation convention, I removed the matrix part to avoid any confusion,  my issue is with the tensor transformation formula, I have no idea where it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are learning tensor calculus with several sources of different ages and backgrounds, you will run afoul of several points of conflicts with the conventions you were exposed to.

**1.** *Different notations developed from several backgrounds that are relatively independent and thus kept/keep their traditions for a long time.*

Despite having predecessors in the 18th and 19th century, matrix and tensor notation was invented and came into wide use only in the late 1920ies. There was the systematic coordinate version of differential geometry in the Ricci calculus as the mathematical apparatus behind general relativity. Then the algebra of infinite matrices in the developing quantum theory in the Heisenberg picture. (These were later replaced by an operator calculus, and the previous matrices only appear if selected eigen-decompositions are applied.) And then several other conventions based on their own histories, related but distinct, and with not so stringent demands on generality, for applications in Euclidean geometry, the mechanics of continua etc. where it was more important to have a compact form for a restricted set of material coefficients and their application in equations.

Your source appears to fall into the latter category.

**2.** *Some conventions are a matter of taste among conflicting requirements.*

The guiding principle exposed in the first half of your question is that linear transformations be written down in the order they occur. That is, if you first apply transformation $C_1$ and then transformation $C_2$, then their combined action be represented by the matrix product $C_1C_2$. Note that this convention underlies also many computer graphics libraries, but is not the prevailing one in mathematics and physics where operators act from the left, so if they are represented as matrices the main vector objects are column vectors.

To have the matrices act properly on the coefficient vector thus needs that vector to the left, making it a row vector. But that is from interpreting it now, it is not clear that the now common identification of a $M_{ij}$ index pair as row and column index in that order was that fixed at the time of the publication of the book, or even if there was only one fixed rectangular scheme to organized these coefficients.

**3.** *Abstract axiomatic versus concrete constructions*

The next point is that in physics the point-of-view is prevailing that a tensor is the data structure with its transformation laws. From a mathematical perspective this looks the same as saying that the real numbers *are* the Dedekind cuts of the rationals (or some other fixed realization of the axioms).

For a mathematician a tensor is an element of a linear space that is the product (of some sorts) of other linear spaces. The transformation laws are then a consequence of the nature of the factor spaces and basis changes there. If the factor spaces are the same vector space and its dual, then these basis changes may be synchronized.

In total it means that the formula under discussion is not something to prove, but it is a *defining property* of $T$ as a tensor. It characterizes it as *doubly covariant*. That is, if ${\bf x}=x_i{\bf e}_i$, then $${\bf T}=T_{ij}({\bf e}_i\otimes {\bf e}_j)$$ acts like a "double vector" (bi-vector?), a sum of products of vectors.

To make the circle complete, if the underlying basis is changed as ${\bf e}_i=C_{im}{\bf e}'_m$, then
$$
{\bf x}=x_iC_{im}{\bf e}'_m=x'_m{\bf e}'_m
\\~\\
{\bf T}=T_{ij}(C_{im}{\bf e}'_m\otimes C_{jn}{\bf e}'_n)
=T_{ij}C_{im}C_{jn}({\bf e}'_m\otimes {\bf e}'_n)
=T'_{mn}({\bf e}'_m\otimes {\bf e}'_n)
$$
But this is truly a circle, as the nature of $T$ was divined from the given transformation law, and the last equation sequence just confirms the compatibility of the mathematical with the physical idea of a tensor.

Note that $C$ acts backwards on the basis change and forwards on the coordinate change, thus the naming of the coordinate tuple as "contra-variant" to the basis tuple.

Comment: Now it's clear to me thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the textbooks on tensors get several things mixed up. To do it properly requires introducing tensors in linear algebra (it's usually called multilinear algebra) and there are two definitions to take care of here (and which are related). Then we need manifolds (basically your bodies as in deformable bodies) and vector bundles over manifolds and then it turns out we can bundle up all the tangent vectors into the tangent bundle which is a vector bundle over the manifold; then finally applying the tensor operation, we get the tensor bundle.

Given all this technology it's perhaps not surprising that textbooks still keep to the the indexful notation, pedagogically speaking, it's simply less hassle - even when terms are introduced without enough explanation or motivation.

> Now, given a second order tensor $T_{ij}$, my textbook defines the transformation under the new rotated coordinate system as $$ T'_{mn} = C_{im}C_{jn}T_{ij}$$

The mistake here is that you can't be given a second order tensor without its transformation law, *the two go together*. The transformation law in effect *defines* the second order tensor. Hence, because it is a *definition* there is *nothing to prove*. What's really required is *motivation* and an *explanation* why second order tensors are a useful thing and why they are defined the way that they are. Unfortunately most books I've looked at do this pretty poorly, so your confusion is quite common - least wise, I was similarly confused.

Comment: Thanks so much. Really my book was not clear about this, now I have a different perspective about transformation of coordinates.

Comment: @Algo: You're welcome. I'm glad my experience of sorting out tensors for myself has been of some use to someone.